# Array in record types

Tags: arrays, ocaml, record

I would like to define a record type with one member being of types array, like this :

```
 type h = {x:int; y:int; pic : Array of int};;
```

This gives a syntax error at `of` location :

```
 type h = {x:int; y:int; pic : Array *of* int};;
```

Now, if I am using an intermediate type to name `Array of int`, it works:

```
 type a = Array of int;;
 type h = {x:int; y:int; pic : a};;
```

Is it a defect or do I miss sth ? (my ocaml version is 4.05.0)

Then, once `type h` is defined I cannot use it :

```
 let n = {x=0;y=0;pic=[| 0 |]};;
```

I got the error :

```
 Error: This expression has type 'a array but an expression was expected of type
     a
```

Comment: you've got the answer, but don't forget to take hints on types from ocaml: a simple `Array.make 10 10` would include `int array` in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of an array of `int`s is `int array`. `type a = Array of int` defines a variant with a single constructor `Array` that takes a payload of type `int`.